# How to remove X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN header from request header in NGINX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, nginx, iframe, amazon-ec2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1lP9.png)

Hello, everyone i need to remove **X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN** header from request header.i use nginx server and all setup is in aws.

i try following solution but it does't work for me.

`proxy_hide_header 'x-frame-options';`

And i got error like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmSgH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done with the out-of-the-box nginx build. Additionally, `proxy_hide_header` directive used to hide headers from upstream, not from client browser. One of the solutions is to use `more_clear_headers` directive from [`ngx_headers_more`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module, but for that you need to build nginx from sources (or use [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) instead).

Comment: Thanks, Ivano 

DO you have any ref. for it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what references do you mean, if you meant OpenResty, look [here](https://github.com/priestjim/chef-openresty).